# Кодирование категориальных переменных и их отбор для модели

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, статистика, статический-анализ, feature-engineering

Делают ли отбор переменных модели после их кодировки? Так, например, у меня есть переменная «квартал», при использовании подхода `dummy` она распадается на 4 переменные. Методы определяющие важность признаков (feature importance) говорят, что один из кварталов — незначимый. Можно ли его «выкинуть» из модели? Или это не верно, потому что все-таки исходная переменная «Квартал»?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это отличный пример [мультиколлинеарности](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C). Если значения признака взаимоисключающие (любая дата может принадлежать только одному кварталу), то после One Hot Encoding один из четырёх новых признаков будет лишним, т.к. все варианты легко описываются тремя признаками - если все три признака равны 0 - это значит что квартал может быть только тем, который не описан в признаках (метод исключения).

Таким образом в вашем случае это не только уменьшит число признаков, но и может улучшить точность модели, т.к. мультиколлинеарность обычно ее ухудшает.

Comment: Большое спасибо!